# merge [cfcard] into [compactflash]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

[cfcard](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cfcard) - 15
[compactflash](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactflash) - 17

I notice we have two very similar tags. If I'm not mistaken these mean the same thing. Should we have a synonym or merge to eliminate the redundancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one's a no brainer. Let's do it.

Bad form edit to bump this to the top of the list: admins (or anyone else who can do this): I think there's consensus here. Is there anything stopping this happening, other than lack of time? Alternatively, if somebody manually retagged all the questions, would that cause a problem?

Comment: Manual retagging is just tedious, and also doesn't automatically create a synonym. But feel free to go for it!